# Why cant I copy folders from external hard drive containing Java files/code?

Tags: windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, java, file-transfer

Today I decided I would finally backup all my files from my external hard drive to my actual PC. I selected all folders from my hard drive and dragged them to a folder in the desktop (essentially just copying). I let it sit in the "Discovering Files" state for a long time since its a lot of folders making up 100+ gigs. But, the "copying" process ends there (on the Discovering X files state). So, I tried dragging folders one at a time. To my surprise, most did copy, but some didn't. After hours of googling, I looked at the folders (that weren't copying), and realized those folders were the ones containing Java code. The 2 folders that weren't copying were my "Minecraft" folder (which I use to make spigot plugins), and my "Java" folder, which I use to put all my small programs in.

Whats going on? Why can I only copy folders that dont contain java code?

Comment: Have you verified you have permissions to these folders? Have you verified you are able to read the files in question?  A 100 GB copy of a USB connection (even USB 3.2 Gen 2) would take a while to prepare and execute.

Comment: Also, have you run a filesystem check to ensure the filesystem is not in a confused state?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I have set the permissions for these folders so that should work. Im having a hard time actually oppening the folders (its freezing and saying "Not Responding"). For the filesystem check, I will do that now.